# use cat to bounce a character between pipes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, pipe

I have been reading about pipes in linux and I came across this in a book (http://linux-training.be/linuxsys.pdf, page 16)

First they create four pipes with mkfifo

```
$ mkfifo pipe33a pipe33b pipe42a pipe42b
```

copy /bin/cat into ./

```
$ cp /bin/cat proj33 && cp /bin/cat proj42
```

Then run the following commands

```
$ echo -n x | ./proj33 - pipe33a > pipe33b
$ ./proj33 <pipe33b >pipe33a &
```

The book explains the last command as

> The commands you see above will create two proj33 processes that use
>   cat to bounce the x character between pipe33a and pipe33b.

My problem is I do not understand the last command. Especially why '-' is used between ./proj33 and pipe33a. What does '-' do. And how does this set-up act like an infinite loop of exchanging the charatier 'x'?

Comment: `-` usually refers to standard input or output dependent on the context, eg. `echo 1 | cat file - > file.out` will append standard input to the content from `file` and write it to `file.out`, while `cat - file` would take standard input first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explanation:
Note for clarity I'm going to call the processes cat1 and cat2 rather than proj33.

1. `echo -n x` outputs the character 'x' and feeds it to `cat1` which is just a copy of the cat command.
2. `cat1 - pipe33a > pipe33b`: First reads stdin (that's what the `-` means) and writes it to `pipe33b`. Then cat1 tries to read from `pipe33a` and it has to wait.
3. `cat2 <pipe33b >pipe33a &` Reads the 'x' out of `pipe33b` and writes it back out to `pipe33a`
4. cat1 can now read the 'x' back out of the `pipe33a` and writes it back out to `pipe33b` starting the whole process over again.

Comment: "it has to wait", key words! Thanks epicbrew!. After the first command (cat1)  and before cat2, I also tried  `ps aux|grep $cat1pid` and it was in sleep. After I ran the second command it started running.

Answer (score 2):

The `-` in the command means that `cat` (or your copy of it, `proj33`) reads from standard input. So `proj33` concatenates standard input and the contents of `pipe33a`, sending them to `pipe33b`.

The second instance of `proj33` reads from `pipe33b` (i.e. the output of the first instance) and sends the output to `pipe33a` (i.e. back to the first instance).

The `-` in the first command is needed to kick-start the process, allowing you to `echo` a character in to the loop.